# Wordpress custom page template returns the theme headers

Tags: json, wordpress

I want to return a JSON array from a Wordpress website. I know this can be done using plugins like WP REST API and JSON API, but I am dealing with custom post types so I want to avoid complexity and write the queries myself.

I have overridden one of my pages by writing a new php file in my theme directory called page-345.php.

Inside my PHP file I have the following code

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'partner',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1 // all
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

$cars = array();

while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

  // Add a car entry
  $cars[] = array(
    'name' => get_the_title()
  );

endwhile;

wp_reset_query();

wp_send_json( $cars );
```

I code works and I get output in JSON. However, JSON in returned alongside the header of the template. (See screenshot)

[image]

I also tried entering the code

```
header( 'Content-type: application/json' );
```

at the top of my page, but then Wordpress returns an error saying that headers have already been set.

Comment: You need to remove `wp_head` and `wp_footer` from your page. But the proper way is to use the [Rewrite_API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API)

Comment: @Erevald I do not have any wp_head and wp_footer in my page

Comment: Is this the only code that you have in `page-345.php`? because what i fell is that through some common theme function nav is showing.

Comment: this is the only code in page-345.php @Raunak Gupta

Comment: can you just do one experiment, create a custom template and assign it to this API page and then check `nav` is still showing or not.

Comment: it still shows the nav @Raunak Gupta

Comment: ok one last experiment, only write `echo 'Hello';` and check what is showing; and can you tell me which theme you are use, because this look quit interesting to me so I would like to know how `nav` is getting appended without `get_header()`